# problem using anchor button in server(cent os)

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project i am using anchor button based on if else condition. In windows it's working perfectly.
HTML

```
    <?php 
            $actionbutton = $row['status'] == 'success' ? 
              anchor('Users/getpdf/'.$row['appno'],'Generate Pdf') : 
            anchor('Users/validate/'.($row['appno']),'Pending') ;
            ?>
            <td align="center"><?php $actionbutton;?></td>
```

after uploading in server (cents os) the button not displayed. how to solve this error?

Comment: Welcome. Are you sure this works on Windows? `<?php $actionbutton;?>` doesn't really output anything.

Comment: if status success , the first call function works else second function working perfectly in windows . but in cent os not responding anything. the button not visible.

Comment: I doubt this works in Windows, you'd need to `<?php echo $actionbutton;?>` for this to work at all. Unless I am completely missing something here.

Comment: last time i checked `$somevar` without an echo doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first command, it assigns the value to your `$actionbutton` variable.
Your 2nd command, I think you want to `echo` the `$actionbutton`.

Maybe you want this `<?=$variable?>`.

So, in your case `<?=$actionbutton?>`

[Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html#alternative-echos)  about alternative syntax.

Comment: super ji its working. thanks for saving my time

Comment: or.... type echo like the first comment suggested 30 mins ago to which you replied it was "magically" working  on windows. no offense @marlo

Comment: @Alex its ok. :)